# "Battery too low to update automatically" message

Tags: notifications, battery-life, lg-g2

My phone is less than a year old, and I really don't use it that heavily, but the battery life is terrible at times (not always).  Sometimes, it will drain to single-digits (percentage-wise), and then a message keeps appearing at the bottom of my screen; about every 5 or 10 seconds.

The message is, "Battery too low to update automatically".  I've googled that message, and there are only 3 or 4 results returned; none of them are relevant to my issue.  That leads me to believe that this message is likely related to a specific app, and not a standard Android or LG message.

Does anyone know how I can find-out what's causing that message?  I feel like, once I locate that issue or application, then I can stop that constant updating, and hopefully prolong some battery life.